# Java regex for extracting nested function in custom format

Tags: java, regex

We are developing a parser for advanced configuration syntax, in which expressions are surrounded by curly braces `{}`, so a function is represented as:

```
{myFunction( arg1 ;; arg2 ;; arg3 )}
```

For processing nested functions, we're using Java's `replaceFirst` with the pattern:

```
String regexStr = "\\{[^(){}.]+?\\([^()]*?\\)\\s*}";
```

Replacing simple functions (functions without a function as arg) with evaluated result successively, thus achieving parsing in a bottom up (or rather inner out) manner:

```
// `args` are the arguments of the function being processed, which could themselves be functions

boolean nestedFunctionsExist;
do {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexStr).matcher(args);
    nestedFunctionsExist = matcher.find();
    if (nestedFunctionsExist) {
        String nestedFunction = matcher.group();
        args = args.replaceFirst(regexStr, String.valueOf(parseSimpleFunction(nestedFunction)));
    }
} while (nestedFunctionsExist);

// parse this function with updated args, none of which should itself be a function now
```

This has worked so far, but now we need to parse a function:

```
{outer( {inner( {x.path[?(@="abc")]} )} )}
```

With the current pattern, `inner` is not detected as a function as the argument contains `()`. How can we adapt the regex to match this? We tried some lookahead and lookbehinds related modifications but without success.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing you would want to do recursively if possible, and not the kind of thing you would want to use regex for (in much the same way as regex can't really handle HTML/XML).

Comment: Regex is not the tool for syntax parsing. Take a look https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-java/

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy We started with a recursive approach, but had to switch to this as in the former we couldn't extract the top level arguments effectively when they could themselves contain arguments (i.e. nested functions).

Comment: @ariel Yes, we are considering using a parser generator if this doesn't work, thanks for the link.